# Upsert R Dataframe into SQL Server

Tags: r, sql-server-2008, merge, upsert

I am trying to Insert and Update into a SQL Server from R.

I have a data frame (New_mtcars) which contains records that do not exist in the SQL Database table (dbo.mtcars) or do exist, but are different.

How do I insert and update (merge?) records from New_mtcars into the Microsoft SQL server table?

I have successfully created a connection string using dbConnect, and established a connection using ODBC.
However, I am struggling with the workflow and syntax beyond this point.

Comment: The `UPSERT` process is completely DBMS-specific, and SQL Server is not without its nuances and requirements. I found the following very helpful when I needed to work with upserts: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql, https://michaeljswart.com/2017/07/sql-server-upsert-patterns-and-antipatterns/, and https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

Comment: From that, I mean that some DBMSs are as straight-forward as inserting into a temp table, then `insert into tblname (var1,var2,...) select var1,var2,... from tmptbl ON CONFLICT (...) DO ...`, where the conflict/do are straight-forward. For SQL Server, not so simple ... `merge tblname with (holdlock) as tgt using (select varnames from tmptable) as src on (varnames) WHEN MATCHED THEN ... WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN ...`. Depending on your needs (and table constraints), it may take a few tries to get it right.